# How would I find all combinations/permutations with order mattering in R?

Tags: r, combn

Hello and thanks for looking. I'm not exactly sure how to ask this question - let me show you an example and what I'm hoping to return.

```
example <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
example_combos <- combn(example, 4)
```

1) How would I adapt combn() to just give me the combinations including the number 1? Additionally, I would like to not allow for sequences of three or more numbers to be in a row.
i.e.: `(1,2,4,5), (1,2,4,6), (1,2,5,6), (1,3,4,5), (1,3,4,6), (1,3,5,6)`

2) Alternatively, how would I actually allow order to matter - meaning `(1,2,4,5)` is different from `(2,4,5,1)`. How would I not allow for sequences of 3 or more in a row in this situation - and then, how would I subset the data frame to just include the columns starting with a 1?

Thank you! Very new to R still!

Comment: Terminology issue here? With combinations of distinct objects, the ordering should not be at issue.  That's a concept that might apply to permutations, but not combinations.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check out permutation functions too, but mainly - how would I add the restriction of no more than 2 numbers in a sequence (ie; never (1,2,3,5))?

Comment: Patience, Grasshopper, I was working on it. Almost done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer (or an answer anyway).

```
example_combos[ , apply( example_combos, 2, function(col){ !any( rle(diff(col))$lengths >= 2 & rle(diff(col))$values==1)   })  ]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    2
[2,]    2    2    2    3    3    3
[3,]    4    4    5    4    5    5
[4,]    5    6    6    6    6    6
```

And here's an explanation:

I'm counting the number of time that a run of 1's in the successive differences of the combinations (which are ordered) occurs in any given column of the example_combos matrix. If its greater than or equal to two that implies a run of at least 3.

Comment: Ok, I'm checking this out. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, thank you a million trillion. Maybe you can help with the next challenge I face. How would I subset by having only columns whose first row is a 1. Additionally, how would I transpose that new set up by 1 but where a 13 = 1 and a 14 =2, etc..

Comment: Oh shoot! And, this is basically a circle, so 11, 12, 1 should never happen either - can you help me adjust?

Comment: The first item being == 1 is just `example_combos[ example_combos[ 1,] == 1 , ]`. But I don't understand the second part about 13=1 and 14=2. Might need another question.